# Converting String to Double in Android

Tags: android, string, double, android-edittext

Trying to get double values from an EditText and manipulate them before passing them to another Intent. Not using primitive data type so I can use toString methods.

Problem is when I include the protein=Double.valueOf(p).doubleValue(); style commands, the program force closes immediately without leaving any info in the logcat.If I comment them out and set some dummy data like protein = 1.0; it works with no problems.
Same happens with primitive data types and parse double. This code works perfectly with dummy data in normal java.
What am I doing wrong?

```
EditText txtProt, txtCarb, txtFat, txtFiber, txtPoints;
String p, c, f, fi;
Double protein, carbs, fat, fiber;
double temp;
Integer points;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     Log.v("Create Prompt", "ready for layout");
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     Log.v("Layout Created", "ready for variable assignment");
     txtProt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Protein);
     txtCarb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Carbs);
     txtFat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Fat);
     txtFiber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Fiber);
     txtPoints = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Points);
     btnCalc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Calc);
     Log.v("Variables Assigned", "ready for double assignment");

     p = txtProt.getText().toString();
     c = txtCarb.getText().toString();
     f = txtFat.getText().toString();
     fi = txtFiber.getText().toString();


     protein=Double.valueOf(p).doubleValue();
     carbs=Double.valueOf(c).doubleValue();
     fat=Double.valueOf(f).doubleValue();
     fiber=Double.valueOf(fi).doubleValue();
     Log.v("Doubles parsed", "ready for calculations");
     //these are the problem statements

     protein = 1.0;
     carbs = 1.0;
     fat = 1.0;
     fiber = 1.0;

     protein *= 16;
     carbs *= 19;
     fat *= 45;
     fiber *= 14;

     temp = protein + carbs + fat - fiber;
     temp = temp/175;

     points = new Integer((int) temp);
```

Comment: From the docs -- getText() Returns the text the TextView is displaying. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText() unless you called setText with a different buffer type?

Comment: For `kotlin` you can use `toDouble()` like this: `val d = textString.toDouble()`

Answer (score 79):

I would do it this way:

```
try {
  txtProt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Protein); // Same
  p = txtProt.getText().toString(); // Same
  protein = Double.parseDouble(p); // Make use of autoboxing.  It's also easier to read.
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  // p did not contain a valid double
}
```

EDIT:  "the program force closes immediately without leaving any info in the logcat"

I don't know bout not leaving information in the logcat output, but a force-close generally means there's an uncaught exception - like a NumberFormatException.

Comment: For `kotlin` you can use `toDouble()` like this: `val d = textString.toDouble()`

Answer (score 27):

try this:

```
double d= Double.parseDouble(yourString);
```

Comment: How does this compare with `Double.valueOf( your String )`?

Comment: this raises NumberFormatException bcz you are not autoboxing double to Double.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to assign **Double** object into native *double* value field. Does that really compile?

Double.valueOf() creates a **Double** object so .doubleValue() should not be necessary.

If you want native *double* field, you need to define the field as *double* and then use .doubleValue()

Comment: Yes it does compile. I am using Double instead of double so I can pass the results to another activity through an intent.putExtra(string,string).

Comment: @jkj: It's called autoboxing, and is a documented feature of Java. (EDIT:  Rather, auto-unboxing in the case of your comment)

Answer (score 2):

What about using the Double(String) constructor? So,

```
protein = new Double(p);
```

Don't know why it would be different, but might be worth a shot.

Comment: Also, you're not catching a NumberFormatExeption anywhere in there -- that might be causing your problem. Might want to catch and log that, too, just in case.

Comment: why would not catching a NumberFormatException cause the program to force close without even opening?

Comment: If you're getting a NumberFormatException somewhere in there, it's going to be tossed up the call stack, into code you don't control. Better to catch it and handle it where you know what it means -- especially when dealing with user input.

Comment: protein = new Double(p); didn't work also couldn't get protein=Double.valueOf(p.trim()); to work. also tried protein=Double.parseDouble(p.trim()); no luck

Comment: Ah. I understand why I should handle it before I finish the program, I am curious if it would affect the program force closing on launch

Comment: It might, because whatever in the Android framework is calling your application's create method may not have a clue how to deal with a NumberFormatException.

Comment: I've answered my own question there. My xml layout had "" as the default value of the edittext fields. I've put in a 0 to the edittext field and added the try catch blocks.

Answer (score 2):

i have a similar problem.
for correct formatting EditText text content to double value i use this code:

```
try {
        String eAm = etAmount.getText().toString();
        DecimalFormat dF = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        Number num = dF.parse(eAm);
        mPayContext.amount = num.doubleValue();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mPayContext.amount = 0.0d;
    }
```

this is independet from current phone locale and return correct double value.

hope it's help;

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but I have just figured out that :

- parsing the EditText value in the Oncreate method caused the app to crash because when the app starts, there are no values to parse or maybe the placeholders which are letter.

My code:

```
package com.example.herodav.volumeapp;

import android.renderscript.Double2;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText height, length, depth;
    TextView volume;
    double h,l,d,vol;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        height = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.h);
        length = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.l);
        depth = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.d);
        volume = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.v);

        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calculateVolume();
                volume.setText("Volume = " + String.valueOf(vol));
            }
        });
    }

    public void calculateVolume(){
        h = Double.parseDouble(height.getText().toString());
        l = Double.parseDouble(length.getText().toString());
        d = Double.parseDouble(depth.getText().toString());
        vol = h*l*d;
    }
}
```

I

Answer (score 1):

```
  kw=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.kw);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    cost=(TextView )findViewById(R.id.cost);


            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { cst =  Double.valueOf(kw.getText().toString());
            cst = cst*0.551;
            cost.setText(cst.toString());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String sc1="0.0";
Double s1=Double.parseDouble(sc1.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double d = Double.parseDouble(aString);
```

Make sure the variable *aString* contains only numerical digits. It may have a '+' or '-' sign at the beginning.

I was using a string having quotations in it and got an error.