# How can I convert string to double?

Tags: java, android, string, double

I am developing an android app. I need to convert string to double. How can I do it?

Comment: Nowadays, many don't seem to Google or read decent Java books. Are developers getting lazy these days?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting String to Double in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866633/converting-string-to-double-in-android)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You just need this :

```
double d=Double.parseDouble(myString);
```

If your `String` value cannot be parsed to double it will throw `NumberFormatException`. So better you put the `parseDouble` statement inside try catch block.

Comment: I think the OP wanted a small-d double, but boxing is okay.

Answer (score 4):

here is the example

```
try{
   double dbl = Double.parseDouble("99.882039");
catch(NumberFormatException ex){
  // handle exception
}
```

Comment: better to catch only NumberFormatException

Answer (score 1):

```
double d = Double.parseDouble(theString);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not a thing of android but if you're sure you string can be expressed as a double you can do it like this with simple Java:

```
Double.valueOf("1.2");
```