# Convert string to double and get original value of string in double

Tags: java, string, double

I want to convert my value from string to double:

```
String mystring = "0.0100";
Double d = Double.parseDouble(mystring);
```

This string is from my edittext.

**problem is** my input string is **0.0100** but when I convert it to double it gives me **0.01** only.

How can I get the original string from the double?

I need all the zeroes as per the example.

Comment: That´s not possible if you are storing it into a double, you will at least need to format it back.

Comment: Well, you want the number, you get the number ... If you need to convert a number back to a String, try using the String formatting options (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Comment: @DaDaDom, i dont want to convert a number back to a string. i want only string to number(as original in string)!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting String to Double in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866633/converting-string-to-double-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is "you cannot do using Double".

A `"double"` value is stored in binary. The idea of trailing decimal zeros, as in 106.4000, is meaningless in a "double" value.

Your problem sounds like a job for `BigDecimal`

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String mystring = "0.0100";
        Double d = Double.parseDouble(mystring);
        System.out.println("Double : "+d);

        BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(mystring);
        System.out.println("BigDecimal : "+bigDecimal);
    }
```

**output**

```
Double : 0.01
BigDecimal : 0.0100
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code, it may help you.

```
String mystring = "0.0100";
Double d = new DecimalFormat("##.####").format(Double.parseDouble(mystring));
```

Comment: what if there were 5 zeros like 0.0100000?

Comment: I think your format needs to `"##.0000"` to ensure all four decimal places are shown.

Comment: Yes but am telling you the number of zeros after 1 are not fixed.

Comment: @DegenSharew in that case, the double itself would work, as there is a zero value to the end of the number after the decimal. It don't have any value. Hence its not being shown. and if there are number after zero in the decimal part it will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

A double stores a floating point value. The concept of four decimal places and 0-padding to the right is a display issue (ie. separate to the value). Therefore take your value and format it in some way, eg.

```
System.out.printf("%.4f, d");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use BigDecimal instead

```
String mystring = "0.0100";
BigDecimal b =  BigDecimal(mystring);

System.out.println("Value b: "+b);//"0.0100"
```